# How to join two tables based on missing values in one table?

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012, records

Apologies, if this question has already been answered earlier. I hunted but couldn't find any.

The problem:

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have two tables (`TableA` and `TableB`) as shown below

**Table A**

```
+-------+--------+
| ItemA | SeqNoA |
+-------+--------+
| D     |      1 |
| A     |      0 |
| Z     |      0 |
| B     |      4 |
| A     |      0 |
| K     |      6 |
+-------+--------+
```

**TableB**

```
+-------+--------+
| ItemB | SeqNoB |
+-------+--------+
| A     |      1 |
| D     |      2 |
| C     |      3 |
| A     |      4 |
| B     |      5 |
| J     |      6 |
+-------+--------+
```

The `TableA` has missing (zero) values in some of the rows of col `SeqNo`, while the same values are present in col `SeqNo` of `TableB`. I need to find some way to join these tables such that I end up with the below given values. This join can either be a join query of some sorts or maybe even creation of a whole new table based on these two table

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| ItemA | SeqNoA | ItemB |
+-------+--------+-------+
| D     |      1 | A     |
| A     |      2 | D     |
| Z     |      3 | C     |
| B     |      4 | A     |
| A     |      5 | B     |
| K     |      6 | J     |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: What is connecting D in TableB to A in TableA?

Comment: The Seqno column is supposed to be the common factor between the two tables, but due to some software goofup, this column is missing some entries in TableA

Comment: If you were to swap rows 2 and 3 in TableA, would you expect the result to change in your final table? If yes: Then you have a real problem. Generally speaking order is not preserved in a database, so these 2 cases are indistinguishable so shouldn't give you a different result. If no: By what criteria should these rows be matched then?

Answer (score 1):

Missing values in column SeqNoA  has value 0. In case you don't have a primary key in your table you can write a query as below by assigning each row a unique sequence number in TableA:

```
select TA.ItemA , TA.NewSeqNoA as SeqNoA , TB.ItemB 
from 
(
select ItemA, SeqNoA , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)) as NewSeqNoA
from tableA ) TA
join tableB TB on TA.NewSeqNoA = TB.SeqNoB
```

but if you have a primary key in tableA then you can modify this query something like below to give you correct row number:

```
select TA.ItemA , TA.NewSeqNoA as SeqNoA , TB.ItemB 
from 
(
select ItemA, SeqNoA , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ('TableA PK')) as NewSeqNoA
from tableA ) TA
join tableB TB on TA.NewSeqNoA = TB.SeqNoB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ON tableB.SeqNo = ISNULL(tableA.SeqNo,tableB.SeqNo)
```

Comment: Isnull won't work here as missing values in column SeqNoA has value 0 not null.

Comment: True, that query is not giving the desired results. Thanks for the effort anyways Grigoryev